# Subscriptions not seen in Salesforce platform events

Tags: platform-event, node.js, aws, entitysubscription, nforce

I am trying to subscribe to Salesforce Platform Events in my Developer Edition through AWS Lambda via Connected App(Using [nforce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nforce) SDK).

Code is as follows:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); //Importing aws-sdk, aws-sdk is node.js sdk for AWS
var nforce = require('nforce'); //Importing nforce, nforce is node.js REST API Wrapper for Salesforce

//Replace these values with your org-specific data - Start
var CLIENT_ID = 'SOME_ID'; //Retrieve from Connected App
var CLIENT_SECRET = 'SOME_SECRET'; //Retrieve from Connected App
var USER_NAME = 'SOME_USERNAME'; //Integration User Name
var USER_PASSWORD = 'SOME_PASSWORD'; //Integration User Password
var TOPIC = 'Won_Quote__e';//Event Name
var REPLAY_ID = -1; //Replay Value

//Replace these values with your org-specific data - End

//Make connection to connected App - Start 
var org = nforce.createConnection({
      clientId: CLIENT_ID, 
      clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET, 
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/_callback',
      //apiVersion: 'v35.0',  // optional, defaults to current salesforce API version
      //environment: 'production',  // optional, salesforce 'sandbox' or 'production', production default
      mode: 'single' // optional, 'single' or 'multi' user mode, multi default
});
//Make Connection to connected App - End

// Authenticate single-user mode - Start
//Declare function as your exports handler, your function should export some thing to Lambda
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
     // authenticate via oauth process to SFDC
    org.authenticate({ username: USER_NAME , password: USER_PASSWORD }, function(err, resp){
          // the oauth object was stored in the connection object
          if(!err) {
              console.log('Cached Token: ' + org.oauth.access_token); //We recieved oauth access token
          }else{
               console.log("Error authenticating to Salesforce, " + err); //There is some problem
          }

          //Initiate listener for listening to salesforce event bus
          var client = org.createStreamClient();

          //Subscribing to Channel for the event
          var accs = client.subscribe({topic:TOPIC, isEvent:true, retry: REPLAY_ID});

          //if Subscription fails, function will disconnect before this
          console.log("Subscription to " + TOPIC + " successful");
    });

}
```

I got a message in the Lamdba that Subscription is successful,
following message, I can see in the logs:

```
console.log("Subscription to " + TOPIC + " successful");
```

But When I look at the Platform Event Object, subscriptions are not available.

[image: Event Subscriptions not available]

Answer (score 0):

That list under the Platform Event object is for Salesforce's internal subscriptions. AWS Lambda subscriptions are external to Salesforce and it would have no way of knowing them.